# mips comparison

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, floating-point-comparison

I'm having an error with my program. I'm not asking someone to necessarily rewrite my program for me, but constructive advice would be appreciated.

```
#print Guess
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Guess
syscall

#get user input
li $v0, 6
syscall

#store it to variable estimate
sw $v0, estimate

#calculate total 
lwc1 $f1, totalSquare
lwc1 $f2, totalCircle
add.s $f0, $f1, $f2
swc1 $f0, total

li $v0, 4
la $a0, totalMsg
syscall
li $v0, 2
mov.s $f12, $f0
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Newline
syscall 

#if  total > estimate, print MSG2. else, print MSG1 
lwc1 $f0, total
lwc1 $f1, estimate
c.lt.s $f0, $f1

bc1t MSG2

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MSG1
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall 

displayMSG2:  
li $v0, 4
la $a0, MSG2
syscall
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is see if $f0 < $f1. If that's NOT true (or in other words, $f0 >  $f1), then branch to "displayMSG2" Else, display MSG1

However, when I run the code, no matter what input I put in, it ALWAYS branches to displayMSG2. I'm pretty new to MIPS and am most comfortable with high-level languages, so I'm really interested in hearing whatever advice ya'll have :)

Comment: What do you have at `total` and `estimatePizzas`? If it's integers then you need to convert to floating point using `cvt.s.w` after `lwc1`.

Comment: @Michael: Technically, non-negative integers have the same ordering as single-precision float bit-patterns; that's why IEEE754 binary32 biases the exponent that way.  In that case you could get away with using FP compares on integer data.  But yeah, without seeing the data at those addresses, or checking with a debugger to see what values are in those FP regs, this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @Michael - probably should've mentioned that in my post, but total and estimatePizzas are both floating point values. My problem is, no matter what the user inputs, it ALWAYS branches to "displayYeah"

Comment: Well, as has been mentioned, it's impossible for anyone else to reproduce the behavior you describe with the code you've posted since it's incomplete.

Comment: @Michael: I was considering putting in the whole code, but because this is for an assignment, I wasn't sure if putting the whole code in would be considered cheating (i.e - other students may be able to access it).

Comment: Debugging is an interactive activity not really suited for Q&A.

Comment: Floating-point values in what format?  single or double?  You're doing single-precision loads and compares.  If you're worried about people copying your assignment, reduce your actual problem to a [mcve] of loads and float-compare, without the printing. (Just a branch that's taken or not.)  You need should also definitely show register values from the MARS debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I posted my full code (changed the variable names and structure of the program a little bit). I'm new to MIPS and MARS so I'm not sure how to access the "register values from the MARS debugger".

Comment: `sw $v0, estimate` is doing an integer store to the 4 bytes at `estimate` (with a bit-pattern from a read-int MARS system call), so that was the problem after all.  The MARS debugger has a register pane, I think it has a tab for FP registers.  Using a debugger is *essential*, it'll stop you wasting your own time (and other people's.)  MARS's is pretty good, and easy to use with the GUI.

Comment: Also, posting your full code is the opposite of minimal for a [mcve].  Now it's full of a bunch of irrelevant printing of prompts and stuff, not just taking input and branching.

Comment: @PeterCordes: sorry if I'm bothering you, but isn't 'li $v0, 6
syscall' (the read MARS syscall I used before 'sw $v0, estimate') in fact a read-float system call?

Comment: Oh yes, it is.  I didn't check the number and just assumed (since you were storing the integer register `$v0`) that you were using read-int.  So actually the problem is that read-float returns in `$f0`, like the manual says: https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html.  You don't need to store/reload it, it's already in an FP reg ready for use.  The bit-pattern stored from `$v0` will be the `6` you loaded as the call number.  (IIRC, MARS's debugger highlights registers that changed on the last single step.  Or if not, at least you'd see $v0 not change.)

Comment: If you want to delete your question, just delete it.  Don't edit to remove the `sw $v0, estimate` instruction which is the key to the whole problem, otherwise it's unanswerable.  It's not a very good [mcve] currently, but at least it has that clue that you're storing an integer bit-pattern and then loading it into a float register.